# Wrong number of rows / columns in nalgebra SMatrix generated from iterator

Tags: rust, nalgebra

The following code:

```rust
let m: SMatrix<f64, 2, 3> = SMatrix::from_iterator((1..).map(|x| x as f64));
println!("{:?}", m);
```

produces the following output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]]
```

The matrix outputed has 3 rows, and each row has 2 columns. In the definition of the matrix however, I asked for 2 rows that each have 3 columns following the nalgebra [documentation](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.29.0/nalgebra/base/type.SMatrix.html).

Expected output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
```

Did I misunderstand what the correct behaviour should be ? If not is this an issue from the nalgebra crate ?

Comment: `SMatrix` equals to `Matrix<T, Const<R>, Const<C>, ArrayStorage<T, R, C>>` with one to one generic argument mapping, as you can see matrix data stored as [ArrayStorage](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.ArrayStorage.html) You can see it from the definition, outer array represent the columns, so there is no problem ^^

Comment: Thank you. First time I see this convention so I was confused.